# cypress origin use : cypress.config.json

Tags: cypress, cross-domain

I try to use "origin" to use multi-domain access, i have configured the cypress.config.js but still have:

> cy.origin() requires enabling the experimentalSessionAndOrigin flag

my cypress.config.js :

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  
      chromeWebSecurity: false,
      e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
         // implement node event listeners here,
              experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true
        },
      },
    });
```

thx for help !
gretings

Answer (score 1):

Move `experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true` above `setupNodeEvents(on, config)`, it's a configuration option not a node event.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
     // implement node event listeners here,
    },
  },
});
```